# Swift 1/2 AutoComplete field case insensitive

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, uitextfield, swift2

i have a code that with json retrieve an array with all names stored in the database, and when you type in the textField, you can see suggestion and so autocomplete. All works great, the only problem is that is case sensitive, in fact if i write "hello" it doesn't find anything, instead if i type "Hello" he suggest the tag.. how can i fix that ? Thank you very much. I didn't find any tutorial about that.

This is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate,UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

let save = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

@IBOutlet var amountPoints: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var reasonView: UITextView!
@IBOutlet var toField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var pointsField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet var autocompleteTableView: UITableView!
var pastUrls: [String] = []
var autocompleteUrls = [String]()
override  func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    toField.delegate = self
    reasonView.layer.cornerRadius = 1
    reasonView.layer.borderWidth = 0.7
    reasonView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor
    autocompleteTableView.delegate = self
    autocompleteTableView.dataSource = self
    autocompleteTableView.scrollEnabled = true
    autocompleteTableView.hidden = true

    getallUser()
    var Names = save.arrayForKey("give.Name")
    pastUrls = Names as! [String]
    print(pastUrls)
}
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}




func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
{
    autocompleteTableView.hidden = false
    let substring = (textField.text! as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)

    searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring(substring)
    return true     // not sure about this - could be false
}

func searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring(substring: String)
{
    autocompleteUrls.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

    for curString in pastUrls
    {
        let myString:NSString! = curString as NSString

        let substringRange :NSRange! = myString.rangeOfString(substring)

        if (substringRange.location  == 0)
        {
            autocompleteUrls.append(curString)
        }
    }

    autocompleteTableView.reloadData()
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return autocompleteUrls.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let autoCompleteRowIdentifier = "AutoCompleteRowIdentifier"
    let cell : UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(autoCompleteRowIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    let index = indexPath.row as Int

    cell.textLabel!.text = autocompleteUrls[index]
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let selectedCell : UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
    toField.text = selectedCell.textLabel!.text
    autocompleteTableView.hidden = true
}








func textViewDidBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) {
    reasonView.text = ""
}

func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    if text == "\n"
    {
        textView.resignFirstResponder()
        return false
    }
    return true
}



@IBAction func giveButton(sender: UIButton) {


}

@IBAction func returnButton(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if you're just trying to do a prefix search, you can use the `hasPrefix:` method.  A simple way to use this method and not consider case would be to get the lowercase version of each string before calling the comparison method:

```
if (myString.lowercaseString.hasPrefix(substring.lowercaseString))
{
    autocompleteUrls.append(curString)
}
```

If you don't mind switching back to `NSString` types, you can also use the `rangeOfString:options:` method:

```
let range = (myString as NSString).rangeOfString(substring, options:[.CaseInsensitiveSearch])
if range.location == 0 {
    autocompleteUrls.append(curString)
}
```